# How to move a file though a website using a background Python script

Tags: python

How can I trigger the following python command from my within HTML code

e.g

```
Import shutil

src ="C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Index/book1.txt

dst ="D:/USBPEN"

shutil.copy(src, dst)
```

This only has to work locally, I'm just using a HTML website to make a GUI and I want to call python commands to move files locally on my machine.

My local apache server is capable of running .py

Could anyone please assist me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make your python script is executable and then you'll be able to call your python script via apache cgi it'll execute. You need `mod_cgi` working to allow you to run python scripts via apache. Let's call the script `copy.cgi` (you can name it anything `.cgi`). First step is to create a file with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

Import shutil
src ="C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Index/book1.txt
dst ="D:/USBPEN"
shutil.copy(src, dst)
```

Note the line at the top of the file `#!/usr/bin/python` will tell your interpreter where python is installed on your machine. To figure out where python is installed go to the shell and type:

```
whereis python
```

Next step is to make your script executable. To do this go back to the shell and type:

```
chmod +x copy.cgi
```

Now you should be able to go to the url: `http://yourip/copy.cgi` and the script will execute on your machine. To put this into your html you can link the url like so:

```
<a href="http://yourip/copy.cgi">copy</a>
```

Hope that helps!

If you're having trouble with `mod_cgi` it may be easier to make a wrapper php script that you can call that subsequently calls your python script. You can do this with the following script `copy.php`.

```
<?php
// Runs the file copy.py and prints the ouput to the browser.
echo exec("python /path/to/your/copy.py");
?>
```

Then just go to the url `http://yourip/copy.php`. Any print statements you add to your python script will be shown in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your help

I can see how this is suppose to work but It doesn't seem to after attempting it

As you predicted I had trouble with the first method so tried the second method you mentioned, using your php wrapper to run the python one

I have both files (copy.py and copy.php) in my htdocs file

The copy.php consists off



<?php
// Runs the file copy.py and prints the ouput to the browser.
echo exec("python /Users/Me/Desktop/copy.py");
?>

and my copy.py consists of

#!/Python27/python

Import shutil

src ="C:/Users/Will/Desktop/Index/book1.txt"
dst ="D:/ereader"
shutil.copy(src, dst)

Comment: Are you able to run `python /Users/Me/Desktop/copy.py` locally? Try putting a line `echo "Hello World";` in your php script and then go to the url and see if you can see `Hello World` to see if it's the php script. You may need to move the python file into the directory that you're serving the apache server on. Can you post the output of when you run the php script?

Comment: I got this to work, repeating the steps you offered again, I can click a link on my main page that triggers  `copy.php`  from http://localhost/copy.php and it will move the file using the `copy.py` file thats stored in C:/xampp/htdocs/copy.py

However, is there a way I can do this in the background without leaving my main webpage which is localhost/EbookLibrary.html thats being used at a GUI. Something that will allow onclick of the image of a button that says [Get This Book], trigger this event?

Essentialy:-  MainPage (click get book button) >trigger php>Run py 
without changing page

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you'll need to add a form with a button and onclick trigger a javascript get request. `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="JavaScript:$.get('copy.php'); return false" />`. To do this you'll need to add this line somewhere in your header: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`